Tuple that accepts only one occurrence of specific type
I'm trying to write a function that accepts a tuple of a union type but a specific member of the union should only appear once (or not at all), e.g. [A, B, A] is valid but [A, B, A, B] is not. Ideally I could just write something like [...A[], B, ...A[]] | A[] but TypeScript doesn't allow it.
While looking for possible solutions I found this answer to a slightly different but related problem: applying a complex constraint to a tuple type. The solution basically intersects the tuple with a generic type that either resolves to unknown or never. Through the use of recursion each member of the tuple can be validated.
Unfortunately my attempt doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why. Apparently I don't understand the solution for the linked question too well. Example code below:
type A = number;
type B = string;

type EnsureOne<Tuple, T, Seen = false> =
  Tuple extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ?
    Head extends T ?
      Seen extends true ?
        { ERROR: [`Only one value of type`, T, `is allowed`] } :
        EnsureOne<Tail, T, true> :
      EnsureOne<Tail, T, Seen> :
    unknown;

type ExpectUnknown = EnsureOne<[A, B, A], B>;
//   ^? unknown
type ExpectError = EnsureOne<[A, B, A, B], B>;
//   ^? { ERROR: ["Only one value of type", string, "is allowed"] }

type Union = A | B;

declare function f<const T extends readonly Union[]>(t: T & EnsureOne<T, B>): void;

const expectError = f([0, '', '']); // no error :(

Playground
When I use EnsureOne on its own it works as expected but in the intersection the constraint has no effect.

Is your question "what is wrong with my failed attempt at X"? If so, please [edit] to make the question specifically about finding the problem with your failed attempt... which is that const type params will tend to infer readonly tuples, and your EnsureOne doesn't expect them. This is easily fixed (I could write up an ans if so). Or, is your question "how should I write X"? If so, then please [edit] to remove the failed attempt and someone can suggest an independent solution.

I guess my question was meant to be primarily the former but be a little open if another way was possible. Not really sure how to rephrase it. Sorry, English isn't my first language. But you basically already provided an answer, thanks for the playground link! If you write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Not exactly part of this question, but I had modified Titians linked solution in the playground to use a const type param instead of a rest param and it still worked without having to use readonly in the extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] part (Playground link). So I still wonder why this is required in my case.

because you put readonly Union[] instead of Union[]. I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Your code should either use readonly or not, but be consistent
Your f() function is generic in a const type parameter T which is constrained to the readonly array type readonly Union[].  That means when you call it like f([0, "a", "b"]) the compiler will infer the type argument for T as the readonly tuple type readonly [0, "a", "b"].
But your EnsureOne type does not expect its first type argument to be a readonly tuple. You are comparing it to the generic variadic tuple type [infer Head, ...infer Tail].  Those don't match. So it becomes unknown and nothing gets rejected.
You could either fix EnsureOne by allowing readonly:
type EnsureOne<Tuple, T, Seen = false> =
    Tuple extends readonly [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ?
    //            ^^^^^^^^ 
    Head extends B ?
    Seen extends true ?
    { ERROR: [`Only one value of type`, T, `is allowed`] } :
    EnsureOne<Tail, T, true> :
    EnsureOne<Tail, T, Seen> :
    unknown;

or you could fix f() and make the constraint not allow readonly:
declare function f<const T extends Union[]>(t: T & EnsureOne<T, B>): void;

or you could do both.  Either way you'd get the behavior you want:
declare function f<const T extends readonly Union[]>(t: T & EnsureOne<T, B>): void;

f([0, "a", "b"]) // error!
// Property 'ERROR' is missing in type '[0, "a", "b"]' but required 
// in type '{ ERROR: ["Only one value of type", string, "is allowed"]; }'.
f([0, 1, 2]); // okay
f([0, 1, 2, "a"]); // okay
f(["a", "b"]); // error!


Another approach
Or, you could rewrite your code to avoid recursive conditional types entirely. One way to do that is to use a mapped array type that compares the Ith element of T to the all the other elements, and if it ever finds that, for example, both the Ith and Jth element are assignable to B (or whatever type you want to check for) when J and I are different, then that element is in error. Error elements can be mapped to the never type or something wacky like { ERROR: ⋯ } (presumably to behave as an "invalid" type as described in microsoft/TypeScript#23689). Otherwise it's left alone.
Perhaps like this:
declare function g<T extends Union[]>(t: [...{ [I in keyof T]:
    T[I] extends B ? (
        unknown extends {
            [J in keyof T]: I extends J ? never : T[J] extends B ? unknown : never
        }[number] ? never : T[I]
    ) : T[I] }]): void;

g([0, "a", "b"]); // error!
g([0, 1, 2]); // okay
g([0, 1, 2, "a"]); // okay
g(["a", "b"]); // error!

This also behaves as desired. I won't go into further detail about how this works, mostly because it seems the question really was about fixing the original approach, and not about implementing a different one.
Playground link to code

Thanks! Very insightful. I think you already explained the alternative approach sufficiently. An invalid type would indeed be great for more complex type constraints like these.
